# Percentage of charted stars

Tags: star, observational-astronomy

I was reading Gene Roddenberry's [guide for TNG writers](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Star_Trek/2_The_Next_Generation/Star_Trek_-_The_Next_Generation_Bible.pdf) and he mentions that that the time of ST:TOS, only 4% of the stars in our galaxy have been charted; this goes up to 19% by the time of TNG. This got me to wondering: what percentage of stars in the Milky Way galaxy have actually been catalogued?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest catalogues, such as Hubble's Guide Star Catalog or the US Navy USNO-B1.0 catalogue have entries for about 1 billion object (mostly stars) with magnitudes down to 21.

The galaxy itself has about [100 billion stars](http://www.space.com/25959-how-many-stars-are-in-the-milky-way.html), but there is considerable uncertainty about that value. The true value could be less or a lot more. Between 50 and 500 billion is the range of uncertainty

So we have catalogued between 0.2% and 2% of the galaxy's stars with best estimate of **about 1%** of stars have been catalogued.

Comment: It is very gratifying to know that Roddenberry took the time to get this one right :)